# Building asp:chart dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have searched this forum and many others around the web, but apparently I'm trying to do something a little different than anyone else.

I have a web page (aspx) that accepts user-entered criteria and selects products based on that user criteria. Using JavaScript, I make an Ajax call to my server side code which interacts with an old, but widely-used company DLL. I receive the matching products and all their details back from the function.

I'm using *result*.substr and *result*.split (since the data is coming back as a comma delimited string) to obtain the relevant pieces of data and build the  section of my table. The user can then click on an icon to the left of each table row to view further details about the selected model.

That displays another  element which extracts further data from the returned comma delimited string. All of that is working beautifully. The problem I'm having is that on the  that displays the further details, there also needs to be a spline chart showing some graphical data. I am returning the data required to plot the spline graphs, but am having trouble finding a way to get the data to the graph.

I would prefer to find a way to set it up just as I have the data table, where I'm using JavaScript to append to the appropriate section of the HTML.

Here is a sample of what I'm doing with the table:

```
 table += '<td title="Details"><div class="details"><img src="/resources/ic_menu_search.png" alt="" height="20" width="20" style="cursor: pointer;" id="' + i + '" ></img></div></td>';
 table += '<td><div class="model">' + TableResults[((i - 1) * 461) + 1] + '</div></td>'; //model
```

Then I do this to put the data in the  section.

```
$('#datatable').append(table);
```

I would like to do something similar with the asp:chart control and maybe try something like:

```
$('#Graph > points').append(TableResults[((recNo - 1) * 461) + (111 + i)]);
```

But, I don't think that is valid. I also tried to use <% %> script tags to set the properties, but it obviously won't run that when the JavaScript/jquery runs. It executes before anything else.

I would also consider doing a server-side (vb.net) function to create the plot points, but I haven't found a good example yet that matches what I'm trying to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ASP.NET chart is a server-side control, I don't think you can do this in pure JavaScript. The best bet is to call web service to render image server-side and then display it to the client, e.g. http://safeery2k.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/using-web-service-to-render-asp-net-chart/. As an alternative cosider using different chart controls more client-friendly, there're plenty out there, e.g. http://docs.fusioncharts.com/free/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: It does look like I will need to use a webmethod/service of some type. I'm trying to locate other examples such as the one you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I use [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to make all my charts and build up the format dynamically in ajax calls. So if a user changes a dropdown list, I pass that new selected index to the ajax page, then it rebuilds the entire table and passes back the html. I don't use the append feature and don't need to contact the code behind using <% %>. I simply use the .html() jQuery function to place all the html in a div.

Comment: Highcharts does look really nice, but I'm afraid I'm going to have to get this to work in-house.